# Ant build results in "NullPointerException" on Eclipse code

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, sap-commerce-cloud

We use Ant for building our Hybris project. While doing the ant clean all we are getting below "Exception" could you please help me on this. We are using Mars.2 Release 4.5.2. And Hybris 6.2.0. Ant 1.9.1.

```
 [yjavac] Internal compiler error: java.lang.NullPointerException at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.dispatch.AnnotationDiscoveryVisitor.resolveAnnotations(AnnotationDisco

 [yjavac] ----------
 [yjavac] java.lang.NullPointerException
 [yjavac]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.dispatch.AnnotationDiscoveryVisitor.resolveAnnotations(AnnotationDiscoveryVisitor.java:236)
 [yjavac]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.dispatch.AnnotationDiscoveryVisitor.visit(AnnotationDiscoveryVisitor.java:75)
 [yjavac]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.Argument.traverse(Argument.java:211)
 [yjavac]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.dispatch.AnnotationDiscoveryVisitor.visit(AnnotationDiscoveryVisitor.java:187)
 [yjavac]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.MethodDeclaration.traverse(MethodDeclaration.java:317)
 [yjavac]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.traverse(TypeDeclaration.java:1379)
 [yjavac]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.CompilationUnitDeclaration.traverse(CompilationUnitDeclaration.java:748)
 [yjavac]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.CompilationUnitDeclaration.traverse(CompilationUnitDeclaration.java:709)
 [yjavac]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.dispatch.RoundEnvImpl.<init>(RoundEnvImpl.java:59)
 [yjavac]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.dispatch.BaseAnnotationProcessorManager.processAnnotations(BaseAnnotationProcessorManager.java:148)
 [yjavac]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.processAnnotations(Compiler.java:818)
 [yjavac]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:434)
 [yjavac]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.batch.Main.performCompilation(Main.java:4136)
 [yjavac]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.batch.Main.compile(Main.java:1694)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor157.invoke(Unknown Source)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 [yjavac]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
 [yjavac]     at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JDTCompilerAdapter.execute(JDTCompilerAdapter.java:80)
 [yjavac]     at de.hybris.ant.taskdefs.YJavaC.executeCompilerAdapter(YJavaC.java:165)
 [yjavac]     at de.hybris.ant.taskdefs.YJavaC.compile(YJavaC.java:100)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.execute(Javac.java:930)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 [yjavac]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 [yjavac]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:396)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 [yjavac]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
 [yjavac]     at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.IfTask.execute(IfTask.java:197)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor19.invoke(Unknown Source)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 [yjavac]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.TaskAdapter.execute(TaskAdapter.java:154)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 [yjavac]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 [yjavac]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:396)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 [yjavac]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 [yjavac]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 [yjavac]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
 [yjavac]     at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.IfTask.execute(IfTask.java:197)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor19.invoke(Unknown Source)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 [yjavac]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.TaskAdapter.execute(TaskAdapter.java:154)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 [yjavac]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 [yjavac]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:396)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 [yjavac]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
 [yjavac]     at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.IfTask.execute(IfTask.java:197)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor19.invoke(Unknown Source)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 [yjavac]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.TaskAdapter.execute(TaskAdapter.java:154)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 [yjavac]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 [yjavac]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:396)
 [yjavac]     at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.ForTask.doSequentialIteration(ForTask.java:259)
 [yjavac]     at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.ForTask.doToken(ForTask.java:268)
 [yjavac]     at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.ForTask.doTheTasks(ForTask.java:299)
 [yjavac]     at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.ForTask.execute(ForTask.java:244)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 [yjavac]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 [yjavac]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:396)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 [yjavac]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 [yjavac]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:396)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 [yjavac]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
 [yjavac]     at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.IfTask.execute(IfTask.java:197)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor19.invoke(Unknown Source)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 [yjavac]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.TaskAdapter.execute(TaskAdapter.java:154)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 [yjavac]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 [yjavac]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:396)
 [yjavac]     at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.ForTask.doSequentialIteration(ForTask.java:259)
 [yjavac]     at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.ForTask.doToken(ForTask.java:268)
 [yjavac]     at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.ForTask.doTheTasks(ForTask.java:299)
 [yjavac]     at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.ForTask.execute(ForTask.java:244)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 [yjavac]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 [yjavac]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:396)
 [yjavac]     at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.ForTask.doSequentialIteration(ForTask.java:259)
 [yjavac]     at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.ForTask.doToken(ForTask.java:268)
 [yjavac]     at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.ForTask.doTheTasks(ForTask.java:299)
 [yjavac]     at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.ForTask.execute(ForTask.java:244)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 [yjavac]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 [yjavac]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:396)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 [yjavac]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
 [yjavac]     at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.IfTask.execute(IfTask.java:197)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor19.invoke(Unknown Source)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 [yjavac]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.TaskAdapter.execute(TaskAdapter.java:154)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 [yjavac]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 [yjavac]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:396)
 [yjavac]     at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.ForTask.doSequentialIteration(ForTask.java:259)
 [yjavac]     at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.ForTask.doToken(ForTask.java:268)
 [yjavac]     at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.ForTask.doTheTasks(ForTask.java:299)
 [yjavac]     at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.ForTask.execute(ForTask.java:244)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 [yjavac]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 [yjavac]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:396)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 [yjavac]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 [yjavac]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:396)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor65.invoke(Unknown Source)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 [yjavac]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
 [yjavac]     at de.hybris.ant.taskdefs.CallMacro.execute(CallMacro.java:58)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 [yjavac]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor53.invoke(Unknown Source)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 [yjavac]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
 [yjavac]     at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.TryCatchTask.execute(TryCatchTask.java:207)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 [yjavac]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 [yjavac]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:396)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 [yjavac]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
 [yjavac]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 [yjavac]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
 [yjavac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
```

Comment: Please add some more details ....

Comment: Please let me know what details you are expecting as I have put the entire stack trace.

Comment: May be duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12394253/ecilpse-java-builder-started-failing.. It doesn't look like a hybris issue, instead some issue with the eclipse.

Comment: I would recommend using a terminal to execute the ant tasks. There are a lot of problems with ant tasks in eclipse.

Comment: @HristoStaykov , I used terminal only. We resolved the issue by replacing the ecj-4.4.2 by ecj-4.6.1. It was a bug in Eclipse compilation process which they fixed in newer version.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably Eclipse bug [472224](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=472224) or [471995](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=471995).

Both of these bugs are marked as being fixed in Eclipse 4.6

Comment: Thanks @greg-449. Your suggestion has helped.

Answer (score 0):

Just use command line

go to platform folder type . ./setantenv.sh or bat

and build type ant clean all